# Removing duplicates from list all together in Python

Tags: python

So I was working on a problem in which, given a list of tuples, I had to return a new list only containing the elements in which the first element of the tuple isn't duplicated. I had no problem removing duplicates but my problem is removing the original element as soon as a duplicate is found. eg.

```
inputList = [("test0", 20), ("test1", 25), ("test0", 30)]
```

This should return

```
[("test1", 25)]
```

I have after my troubles gotten it to work, however I fear my code is bad and that there is a much easier way to perform what I have done.
I've done it by first removing duplicates

```
visited = set()
marked = []
output = []
for key, value in resList:
    if not key in visited:
        visited.add(key)
        output.append((key, value))
    else:
        marked.append(key)
```

I then check my new output list against my marked list

```
resList = []
for mark in marked:
    for i in range(len(output)):
        if mark != output[i][0]
            resList.append(output[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply using list comprehension like so:

```
list1 = [x[0] for x in inputList]

outputList = [(x, y) for x, y in inputList if list1.count(x) == 1]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First count how many times the first element appears in the list. For this purpose we use a dictionary `d`. Then use a simple list comprehension.

```
d = dict()
for x, y in inputList:
  d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1
outputList = [(x, y) for x, y in inputList if d[x] == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count occurrences in `inputList`, then filter out any items that occur more than once.

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(t[0] for t in inputList)
result = [t for t in inputList if count[t[0]] == 1]

print(result)  # -> [('test1', 25)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the output if it is not yet there. If it's already there, remove it and blacklist it (to avoid adding it again).

```
inputList = [("test0", 20), ("test1", 25), ("test0", 30)]

removed = set()
output = []
for key, value in inputList:
    keyfound = False
    for refkey, refvalue in output:
        if key == refkey:
            keyfound = True
            removed.add(key)
            output.remove((refkey, refvalue))
    if keyfound == False and key not in removed:
        output.append((key, value))

print(output)
```